# How to assign the attribute of SubFactory instead of the SubFactory itself

Tags: django, factory-boy

I need the attribute of the SubFactory instead of the object created by it.

```py
# models.py
class User:
    pass

class UserProfile:
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Job:
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


# factories.py
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class UserProfileFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)

class JobFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Job

    # for certain reasons, I want to use UserProfileFactory here but get the user generated from it
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserProfileFactory).user  # doesn't work but you get the idea
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way is to combine [`class Params`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#simple-parameters) and [`factory.SelfAttribute`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#selfattribute):

```py
class JobFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Job

    class Params:
        profile = factory.SubFactory(ProfileFactory)

    user = factory.SelfAttribute("profile.user")
```

A parameter is used inside the factory, but discarded before calling the model.

This way:

- You can provide a profile to the factory if you have it around: `JobFactory(profile=foo)`
- You can set some sub-field of the profile' user: `JobFactory(profile__user__username="john.doe")`

Comment: This looks great! Wasn't aware this was possible honestly. Docs just listed traits and simple params under that Params inner class.

Comment: This gives me a "Cyclic lazy attribute definition" error

Answer (score 1):

I went with the approach below which might be useful to some:

```
user = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: UserProfileFactory().user)
```

That said, it's not documented if this is a legitimate way of using factories, so feel free to correct if this is wrong.

Comment: The issue with using `LazyFunction` in this manner is that the strategy is not passed along to the subfactory: if you call `JobFactory.build()` to avoid inserting into the DB, the `UserProfileFactory` in your example would still insert in the database.